# How do you represent nested types using the Scott Encoding?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, lambda-calculus, algebraic-data-types, scott-encoding

An ADT can be represented using the Scott Encoding by replacing products by tuples and sums by matchers. For example:

```
data List a = Cons a (List a) | Nil
```

Can be encoded using the Scott Encoding as:

```
cons = (λ h t c n . c h t)
nil  = (λ c n . n)
```

But I couldn't find how nested types can be encoded using SE:

```
data Tree a = Node (List (Tree a)) | Leaf a
```

How can it be done?

Comment: I am not sure, but I think it's encoded in the same way you would encode `data Tree a = Node a | Leaf a`, i.e. `node = (λ x n l. n x)`, etc. After all, the list encoding didn't care about the recursive reference -- the encoding is the same as for `data List a = Cons a a | Nil`. Still, I am not familiar enough with SE to write an actual answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mogensen%E2%80%93Scott_encoding#Definition) is correct, then

```
data Tree a = Node (List (Tree a)) | Leaf a
```

has Scott encoding

```
node = λ a . λ node leaf . node a
leaf = λ a . λ node leaf . leaf a
```

It looks like the Scott encoding is indifferent to (nested) types. All it's concerned with is delivering the correct number of parameters to the constructors.

Answer (score 4):

Scott encodings are basically representing a `T` by the type of its case expression. So for lists, we would define a case expression like so:

```
listCase :: List a -> r -> (a -> List a -> r) -> r
listCase []     n c = n
listCase (x:xs) n c = c x xs
```

this gives us an analogy like so:

```
case xs of { [] -> n ; (x:xs) -> c }
=
listCase xs n (\x xs -> c)
```

This gives a type

```
newtype List a = List { listCase :: r -> (a -> List a -> r) -> r }
```

The constructors are just the values that pick the appropriate branches:

```
nil :: List a
nil = List $ \n c -> n

cons :: a -> List a -> List a
cons x xs = List $ \n c -> c x xs
```

We can work backwards then, from a boring case expression, to the case function, to the type, for your trees:

```
case t of { Leaf x -> l ; Node xs -> n }
```

which should be roughly like

```
treeCase t (\x -> l) (\xs -> n)
```

So we get

```
treeCase :: Tree a -> (a -> r) -> (List (Tree a) -> r) -> r
treeCase (Leaf x)  l n = l x
treeCase (Node xs) l n = n xs

newtype Tree a = Tree { treeCase :: (a -> r) -> (List (Tree a) -> r) -> r }

leaf :: a -> Tree a
leaf x = Tree $ \l n -> l x

node :: List (Tree a) -> Tree a
node xs = Tree $ \l n -> n xs
```

Scott encodings are very easy tho, because they're *only* case. Church encodings are folds, which are notoriously hard for nested types.